# cytoscape js filter does not work when you pass a parameter to the filter item

Tags: javascript, php, cytoscape.js

I have a network set up well. But what I want to do is pass the name of the node through the `$_post`, so from the e.g. `cytoscape.php?name=xxxxx`, one can get the xxxxx, and pass it to JavaScript and afterwards highlight in the network by the following code. But so far I find the code works with certain value but not with the passed variable `js_variable1`.

```
var slec=cy.elements("node[name=js_variable1]")
//var slec=cy.filter('node[name=js_variable1]');
 slec.select();
cy.center( slec );
```

Comment: please post your code as a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with more information

Comment: Also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if `name` is a string it should be like `"node[name='asd']"` with single quotes